# filter_var and validating integer values

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate if my variable is a 32-bit signed integer.

I thought I could use `filter_var()` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` but apparently PHPs definition of an int is something entirely different, `999999999999999999` passes without problem.

Looking at the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) it dosn't say anything specific. So what actually does `filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` validate?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793578/regex-for-a-valid-32-bit-signed-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies more with [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except for Windows, which is always 32 bit. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` allows for min_range and max_range to be passed as options. You should probably use those.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your own limits for `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`:

```
$int = 999999999999999999;
$min = 1;
$max = 2147483647;

if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options"=>
    array("min_range"=>$min, "max_range"=>$max))) === false) {
    echo("Variable value is not within the legal range");
} else {
    echo("Variable value is within the legal range");
}
//This will output "Variable value is not within the legal range"
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_int.asp

Integer max size is based on the system:

on a `32-bit system` : INT max will be `2147483647`

on a `64-bit system` : INT max will be `9223372036854775807`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing problems when using the limits for `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` as well.  After some trial and error of testing for the magic maximum number it came out to be 899795648511 on my machine.  Here are my test results:
[image]

**Edit:**
The testing above was done by hard coding the test values into the PHP script as the max_range number.  However, entering 899795648511 into the form field caused an error message to be generated that said "must be a whole number <= 2,147,483,647".  So, this confirms dbruman's and Magicprog.fr's posts that the max limit is determined by 32-bit/64-bit platform.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ctype_digit` to check if it is an integer.

By default the maximum size for integer in PHP is in `0 - 2147483647` range.

It also depends in your platform, this works for 32bit platform.

Usually, this is the case.

```
if (ctype_digit(2147483647)) {
    echo 'integer';
}
if (!ctype_digit(2147483648)) {
    echo 'not an integer';
}
if (!ctype_digit(-2147483647)) {
    echo 'not an integer';
}
```

Comment: The input to `ctype_digit` should be a **string**. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php