# How to check if the next 3 input is an int by using Scanner.hasNextInt() and loop only in java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

How can I check if the next three input user is giving is an int value,
like let's say there is three variables,

- var1
- var2
- var3

And I am taking input as,

`Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
 var1 = sc.nextInt();
 var2 = sc.nextInt();
 var3 = sc.nextInt();`

Now if I want to use `while(sc.hasNextInt())` to determine if the next input is an int or not then it will only check if the next input for var1 is int or not and won't check for the other to variables, **var2**, **var3**. One thing can be done by using **`while loop`** with **`if (condition)`**. For example,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
   var1 = sc.nextInt();
   if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
      var2 = sc.nextInt();
      if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
         var3 = sc.nextInt();
      }
   }
 }
```

But this looks lengthy and needs a lot to write. For similar issue I have seen for **Language C** there is a method for **`scanf()`** which can do the trick. For example,

`while(scanf("%d %d %d", &var1, &var2 & var3) == 3) {
 // Statements here
 }`

So my question is there any such features available in java's **`Scanner.hasNextInt`** or **`Scanner.hasNext("regex")`**.

I have also tried `sc.hasNext("[0-9]* [0-9]* [0-9]*")` but didn't worked actually.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasNext(regex)` tests only single token. Problem is that default delimiter is one-or-more-whitespaces so `number number number` can't be single token (delimiter - space - can't be part of it). So `sc.hasNext("[0-9]* [0-9]* [0-9]*")` each time will end up testing only single `number`. BTW in your pattern `*` should probably be `+` since each number should have at least one digit.

To let spaces be part of token we need to remove them from delimiter pattern. In other words we need to replace delimiter pattern with one which represents only line separators like `\R` ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125)). This way if user will write data **in one line** (will use enter only after third number) that line would be seen as single token and can be tested by regex.

Later you will need to set delimiter back to one-or-more-whitespaces (`\s+`) because `nextInt` also works based on single token, so without it we would end up with trying to parse string like `"1 2 3"`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("\\R");
System.out.print("Write 3 numbers (sepate them with space): ");
while(!sc.hasNext("\\d+ \\d+ \\d+")){
    String line = sc.nextLine();//IMPORTANT! Consume incorrect values
    System.out.println("This are not 3 numbers: "+line);
    System.out.print("Try again: ");
}
//here we are sure that there are 3 numbers
sc.useDelimiter("\\s+");//nextInt can't properly parse "num num num", we need to set whitespaces as delimiter

int var1 = sc.nextInt();
int var2 = sc.nextInt();
int var3 = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("var1=" + var1);
System.out.println("var2=" + var2);
System.out.println("var3=" + var3);
```

Possible problem with this solution is fact that `\d+` will let user provide number of any length, which may be out of `int` range. If you want to accept only `int` take a look at [Regex for a valid 32-bit signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793578/regex-for-a-valid-32-bit-signed-integer). You can also use `nextLong` instead, since `long` has larger range, but still it has max value. To accept any integer, regardless of its length you can use `nextBigInteger()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `nextLine` method and usage of `Pattern`. Regex is matching with 3 numbers which is separeted with space. So it can be like this i think ;

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+\\s[0-9]+$");
while(!p.matcher(scanner.nextLine()).find()){
    System.out.println("Please write a 3 numbers which is separete with space");
}
System.out.println("Yes i got 3 numbers!");
```

I hope this helps you.