# Regex for 16 bit signed integer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have been trying to make the regex of 16 bit signed integer(`-32768` to `32767`) taking reference from this [link of 32 bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20793578/1999190).

Till now, I tried this:

```
^-?([0-9]{1,5}|32[0-6]{3}|32[0-6]{2}|327[0-5][0-8])$|^(-32768)$
```

But, its not matching well.

Please guide.

Comment: Why not just do it numerically? It's not really a job for regular expressions.

Comment: Just use `if (intUs >= -32768 && intUs <= 32767)` ... save yourself the headache of a cryptic regex which would be hard to interpret and maintain.

Comment: I agree with @Pointy. You *could* do this via regex but it isn't a very good idea. I assume this is for some sort of validation - isn't it possible to have a custom validator there?

Comment: I understand the complexity of regex though,  I just want a uniform code as there are many other regex used.. which are relatively simpler... For using if() i will have to change a lot of code.

Comment: It's short *signed* integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (however using regexp is not good idea - `if` is better)

```js
let r=/^(-?(\d{1,4}|[012]\d{4}|3[01]\d{3}|32[0123456]\d{2}|327[012345]\d{1}|3276[01234567])|-32768)$/;

// test
console.log("-32768", r.test("-32768")) ;
console.log(" -9876", r.test("-9876")) ;
console.log("  9876", r.test("9876")) ;
console.log(" 32767", r.test("32767")) ;
console.log("-32769", r.test("-32769")) ;
console.log(" 32768", r.test("32768")) ;
```

Comment: @Shachi I paste to regex101  [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/cqOb3s/1) and it works