# JFlex signed integer regular expression

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, bnf, jflex

I'm trying to create regex that will match integer value which starts from `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`. As I noticed, JFlex not support `\w, \d, ^, $`.

I tried to write some regex like this in flex file. It compiles, but not working.

```
INTEGER = (0|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,8}|[1]{1}[0-9]{1,9}|[-]{1}[2]{1}([0]{1}[0-9]{8}|[1]{1}([0-3]{1}[0-9]{7}|[4]{1}([0-6]{1}[0-9]{6}|[7]{1}([0-3]{1}[0-9]{5}|[4]{1}([0-7]{1}[0-9]{4}|[8]{1}([0-2]{1}[0-9]{3}|[3]{1}([0-5]{1}[0-9]{2}|[6]{1}([0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}|[4]{1}[0-8]{1}))))))))|(\+)?[2]{1}([0]{1}[0-9]{8}|[1]{1}([0-3]{1}[0-9]{7}|[4]{1}([0-6]{1}[0-9]{6}|[7]{1}([0-3]{1}[0-9]{5}|[4]{1}([0-7]{1}[0-9]{4}|[8]{1}([0-2]{1}[0-9]{3}|[3]{1}([0-5]{1}[0-9]{2}|[6]{1}([0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}|[4]{1}[0-7]{1})))))))))
```

Is there any possible way to do that? Or maybe there is some easier way to create such regex?

**Edit:**

I found regex for this from this question:
[Regex for a valid 32-bit signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793578/regex-for-a-valid-32-bit-signed-integer)

Regex is:

`\b([0-9]{1,9}|1[0-9]{9}|2(0[0-9]{8}|1([0-3][0-9]{7}|4([0-6][0-9]{6}|7([0-3][0-9]{5}|4([0-7][0-9]{4}|8([0-2][0-9]{3}|3([0-5][0-9]{2}|6([0-3][0-9]|4[0-7])))))))))\b|-\b([0-9]{1,9}|1[0-9]{9}|2(0[0-9]{8}|1([0-3][0-9]{7}|4([0-6][0-9]{6}|7([0-3][0-9]{5}|4([0-7][0-9]{4}|8([0-2][0-9]{3}|3([0-5][0-9]{2}|6([0-3][0-9]|4[0-8])))))))))\b`

I removed `\b` in `.bnf` and `.flex` also.

This regex is compiles well in `.bnf` file, `.flex` generates class without error's, but nothing work's. I tested this regex in both online tests:

[flex regex test](https://www.regextester.com/104875)

[regex test](https://regex101.com)

But in test's everything is fine. Where did I made a mistake?

Comment: What's the point of using `{1}`? It's 100% noise, as far as I can see. (And writing `[1]` instead of `1` is marginal, as well.)

Comment: @rici thank you for your comment. I removed that, but nothing works still.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the correct regex for that was:

`([0-9]{1,9}|1[0-9]{9}|2(0[0-9]{8}|1([0-3][0-9]{7}|4([0-6][0-9]{6}|7([0-3][0-9]{5}|4([0-7][0-9]{4}|8([0-2][0-9]{3}|3([0-5][0-9]{2}|6([0-3][0-9]|4[0-7])))))))))|-([0-9]{1,9}|1[0-9]{9}|2(0[0-9]{8}|1([0-3][0-9]{7}|4([0-6][0-9]{6}|7([0-3][0-9]{5}|4([0-7][0-9]{4}|8([0-2][0-9]{3}|3([0-5][0-9]{2}|6([0-3][0-9]|4[0-8])))))))))`

I was inattentive. I didn't noticed one more `\b` in regex.